# CakePHP 2.x - Some fields are not complete in request data

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having trouble trying to manage data from a form. The problem is that when submitting a form, some of the data gets normally sent (as always), but some other data is seen as empty.

This is the case: when I submit my form, in Chrome tools (Network tab), I can see the request payload that has all the data correctly formatted, but when dumping the `$this->request->data` variable in my controller, I can see that some of the fields are missing.

For example, I have a multiple-select with `name='data[GamesHome]'`, and another one with `name='data[GamesMenuDesktop]'`, and when selecting some options for each select and submitting, this is the request payload that generates:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryMluBtWwVE1VAOgZ3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[GamesHome][]"

13258
------WebKitFormBoundaryMluBtWwVE1VAOgZ3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[GamesHome][]"

995
------WebKitFormBoundaryMluBtWwVE1VAOgZ3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[GamesMenuDesktop][]"

13893
```

But when dumping the `$this->request->data` attribute, I can see that the GamesHome array has the two correct ids (13258 and 995), but the GamesMenuDesktop is empty.

What is causing this? The request is sent correctly, so I assume that the problem persists in my Controller...

Thanks!

Edit: here's the HTML of the form

```
<form class="well" id="DomainAdminEditForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DomainGamesHomeDesktop">GamesHome</label>
        <select class="form-control select-multiple-games-ajax select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" id="DomainGamesHomeDesktop" name="data[GamesHome][]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <!---Various <option> tags-->
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DomainGamesMenuDesktop">GamesMenuDesktop</label>
        <select class="form-control select-multiple-games-ajax select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" id="DomainGamesMenuDesktop" name="data[GamesMenuDesktop][]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <!---Various <option> tags-->
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please post the form, so to better understand the problem.

Comment: @anujarora Sure! Updated the main post!

Comment: I tried the same, but for me data printed correctly. Can you please tell, how much is the data? As issue can be due to lot of data.

Comment: @anujarora Yeah, the request payload gets really long. Could this be a problem? Maybe a solution could be to split the form into little subforms or something?

Comment: Split the form is not solution, you need to increase the limit of `max_input_vars` in php.ini. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Did increase in limit of `max_input_vars` helped?

Comment: @anujarora Not in my production server! I finally opted to sepparate some fields of the form into another form; it was a priority task so I didn't have much time to fix it. But thanks for your reply, I didn't know it even existed such configuration! 